# Surds and finding the answer for A & B

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been given the following mathematic equation to solve for $A$ and $B$.
I have gone through my knowledge of simplifying surds. Currently, I have gone down to:
Square root $45 = 3\sqrt{5}$
Square root $40 = 2\sqrt{10}$
This is about as far as I can get before I get lost in where to go.

If you cannot see the picture it is: 
Square root $45az^3$ divided by $40y$. The answer is to in the format of:
$A \sqrt{az}$ divided by $B \sqrt{2y}$

> $$ \sqrt{\frac{45az^3}{40y}}= \frac{A\sqrt{az}}{B\sqrt{2y}} $$
>    https://i.stack.imgur.com/kj7ad.png

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. If you want help here please [edit] the question to show us what you have tried and where you are stuck. Do not post a picture - use mathjax: : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with `division-algebras`?

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with division algebras. Could you please read the tag definitions before selecting some at random.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\sqrt{45az^3} = \sqrt{(3z)^25az} = 3z\sqrt{5} \sqrt{az}$ on the numerator, and $\sqrt{40y} = \sqrt{2^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 2y} = 2\sqrt{5} \sqrt{2y}$.
So we have $\frac{A}{B} = \frac{3z \sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{5}} = \frac{3z}{2}$. 
So the simplest forms for $A$ and $B$ is $A=3z$ and $B=2$.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\sqrt{45az^3}}{\sqrt{40y}}=\frac{z\sqrt{45}\sqrt{az}}{\sqrt{20}\sqrt{2y}}$
So, we have $A = z\sqrt{45}$ and $B = \sqrt{20}$

Since we have, $\frac{A}{B}=\frac{z\sqrt{45}}{\sqrt{20}} \Rightarrow \frac{3z\sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{5}}$

$\therefore, A = 3z ~~ \rm{ and } ~~ B= 2$